# How do I get enough Great Works for Radio Free Europe?

Tags: achievements, civilization-5

[image: Picture of achievement]

I already won a Space Victory, but made a save game. I am very late into the game and have already digged out all hidden (I have the Explorer Social Policy) and all visible heritage sites with archaeologists.

My cities are made for great people generation and have a lot of culture, but yet, I have only 6 out of 10 Songs (Great Works required for the Broadcast Towers).

Is there any way to salvage this game to get this achievement?

What are my options to get more musicians?

Comment: You're better off starting another game and focusing on culture/faith. You can generate a ton of musicians and late game you can buy more with faith.

Comment: What are the prerequesites to buy musicians with faith? I can only buy Great Scientists and Prophets along the normal missionary etc. Feel free to make an answer that involves starting a new game, I'll accept it, if it is comprehensive. A Leader suggestion would be nice. In my current game I played as Poland to get 3 achievements from beating the game.

Comment: I believe I used Poland as well. Will post an answer tonight

Comment: You can purchase great musicians with faith if you have adopted all of the policies in the Aethistics tree. http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Social_policies_(Civ5)#Aesthetics

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *only* way to generate Great Musician's is building the musician's guild and setting specialists to work on it. There are however, several ways to speed up that process.

**NOTE**: You *must* have the specialists working the musician's guild for the +% Great Person bonuses to actually affect the generation of Great Musicians from the guild. If you don't have the specialists working the guild, you will always have 0 generation no matter how many of the following bonuses you have. Though the instant ways to get Great People will still, of course, work.

As for a leader Suggestion I went with Pedro II of Brazil for the 50% Great Musician/Writer/Artist boost during golden ages.

## Faster Great Person generation

**Aesthetics** (Social Policy Tree)

- Adopting this policy tree increases Great Musician/Writer/Artist generation by +25%

**Arts Funding** (World Congress Resolution)

- +33% generation of Great Artists/Musicians/Writers, at the cost of -33% generation of the other Great People.

**Avant Garde** (Freedom Level 1 Ideological Tenet)

- +25% Great Person Generation in All Cities.

**Garden** (Building)

- Requires Theology, City next to River or Lake
- +25% Great People Generation in this City.
- The Hanging Gardens Wonder (requires Tradition, Mathematics) provides a free Garden.

**Hero of the People** (Order Level 1 Ideological Tenet)

- +25% Great Person Generation in All Cities.

**Leaning Tower of Pisa** (World Wonder)

- Requires Printing Press
- +25% Great People Generation in all Cities

**Liberty** (Social Policy Tree)

- Getting all 5 Policies in Liberty will let you choose a Free Great Person.

**National Epic** (National Wonder)

- Requires Drama & Poetry, Monument in All Cities.
- +25% Great people Generation in this City.

## Instant Great Persons/Musicians

**Aesthetics** (Social Policy Tree)

- Adopting all policies in this tree allows you to buy Great Musician/Writer/Artists with faith beginning in the Industrial Era.

**Broadway** (World Wonder)

- Requires Radio
- Grants 1 free Great Musician in the city this wonder is built in.

**Leaning Tower of Pisa** (World Wonder)

- Requires Printing Press.
- 1 Free Great Person of your Choice.

**Patronage** (Social Policy Tree)

- Finishing the Patronage Social Tree will result in City-States occasionally gifting you Great People. Not as reliable, but is an option.

**To the Glory of God** (Reformation Belief)

- Taking this reformation belief allows you to purchase any Great Person with Faith beginning in the Industrial Era.

Comment: Isn't there also a religious belief you can choose that allows you to purchase any type of Great Person starting in the Industrial era?

Comment: That's a good point. I'm not sure what it is of the top of my head but I will look it up and add it in.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to get Great Works of Music:

1. **Make them yourself via Great Musicians.** Either build the Musician's Guild early in the game (so that you will have accumulated many Great Musicians by the end of the game), or fill the Aesthetics cultural policy tree so you can purchase Great Musicians with Faith once you hit the Industrial era. Ideally, do both: taking the Aesthetics tree will also make you generate more Great Musicians, and accumulate Faith so you can purchase even more.
2. **Take them from others.** Go to war against other civilizations who have Great Works of Music. The first few cities you capture won't have any because your opponent will almost certainly evacuate them from the city before you take it, but eventually they'll run out of extra Great Work slots and you'll start capturing Great Works as you capture cities.

You can also trade Great Works with other nations, but this won't help you accumulate more Great Works of Music. Alas, you can't swap your Great Works of Writing for Great Works of Music; you can only swap for works of the same type.

Answer (score 0):

Finishing Aesthetics, building National Epic and Garden, and the Avant Garde tenet each give +25% so those four right there will double a city's output.  A fully loaded Musicians Guild gives 3 GPP for the guild itself, and then 3 GPP for each specialist working it, for a total of 9 GPP.  Doubling it as I mentioned yields 18 GPP/turn.

Assuming no other bonuses (i.e., Brazil or Arts Funding) or free Musicians (i.e., Broadway), then you need 100+200+300...+700 = 2800 GPP / (18 GPP/turn) = 156 turns to generate 7 musicians.  This is 156 turns *after* learning Acoustics and building the Musicians Guild and fully loading it.

Since you've finished the Aesthetics tree, you just have to spend 1000+1500+2500 = 4000 faith to generate the last 3 musicians.  Over the course of the same 156 turns, it means you need to generate on average 26 faith/turn.  Your early cities will have to generate the lion's share of this faith, since you'll probably just built the last few cities in the late game specifically to house a broadcast tower.

Reliquary and few Holy Sites should be sufficient in generating enough faith.  Liturgical Drama adds +1 faith for an Amphitheater you need to build anyway, and the New Deal tenet will boost your Holy Sites too.

This is all without having to compete for Wonders, Reformation beliefs or World Congress votes.  You *might* have to race the CPU for the Reliquary and Liturgical Drama beliefs, but there are certainly lots of ways of earning the requisite amount of faith, like being allied with religious city states.